# How to make smooth transition from one widget to another like a pro in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I have shopBasket icon. when pressed, i want it to make smooth transition to another icon. below are icons. any widget for that? i know there are some options like AnimatedContainer. but how to use it in this case?

[image] => [image]

**EDITED**

i have solved using `AnimatedCrossFade`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class IconAnimateWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IconAnimateWidgetState createState() => _IconAnimateWidgetState();
}

class _IconAnimateWidgetState extends State<IconAnimateWidget> {
  bool _firstChild = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedCrossFade(
          firstCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          secondCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          firstChild: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _firstChild = !_firstChild;
                });
              },
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Expanded(child: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag)),
                ],
              )),
          secondChild: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                _firstChild = !_firstChild;
              });
            },
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          crossFadeState: _firstChild
              ? CrossFadeState.showFirst
              : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        );
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps for others

Comment: Try `AnimatedCrossFade`

Comment: add your code .

Answer (score 1):

Simply use AnimatedSwitcher:

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
  child: _isBasket ? Icon(Icons.shopping_bag) : Icon(Icons.add_circle),
)
```